# Can't enter GNU GRUB boot menu!

Tags: linux-mint, login, keyboard, password

so I booted up an old Linux Mint machine today and I can't seem to remember the password. So I wanted to reset the password using the instructions on Mint's website but when I hold shift the GNU GRUB boot menu does not seem to come up. It just asks me for my password then shows me the login screen.

To clarify, I know the system password but not the login password.

I initially assumed it was because I was using a USB keyboard at first but that does not appear to be the problem as it is recognizing the keyboard immediately and I can enter Bios.

Any help would be appreciated.

Password Reset Page - http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download in other machine a live distro (if you have 64bit , download 64 and if you have 32bit download 32 bit), Then step by step do the following steps:

1. Boot with your live cd
2. create a dir
3. mount your old linux on your dir
4. chroot dir
5. Now , you have old linux and you can change password, and manipulate grub and run grub-install

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I ever did was remove grub and go back to lilo. On older machines still  using MBR, and nothing fancy, lilo is so much easier to understand and never does anything strange.